# Is it possible to easily compile and run code in another machine in Visual Studio/Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

Let's say I am developing a program that needs a bit more power than a netbook can provide and I have a good computer at home connected to the internet.

Is there any *easy* way to code in the netbook while I'm not at home and then when building, making it go and run on the computer at home?

I know running programs on other computers isn't a problem, but I'd like to know if it is possible to have an easy experience (it's still possible to debug, etc).

Thanks

Comment: Save to a repository, which then builds and installs and runs the code. Then use remote debugging to see what is going on.

Comment: Also consider Remote Desktoping into one machine or the other.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible for Java code and Eclipse. But there are issues as well.

1. It helps a great deal if you have a fixed IP.
2. You need to open up ports on your firewall to be able to

   - copy your code into your PC
   - remote debug and upload your application
3. The last step will create issues with security that you need to address. I use ssh and public/private key to secure my connections.

In general, what you are asking is not much different to releasing a code to a server and debugging it. And normally servers sit somewhere on the internet or cloud.